# How to use Angular2 as a non-SPA?

Tags: angular

I have just started out with Angular2 and found out that all tutorials that can be found on the web only explains how to setup Angular2 for Single Page Apps (SPA).

However for the homepage of my site I still want to use PHP and just use Angular2 on a few places like Login/Signup/Contact, etc.

How is that possible to initialize the Contact Component on the contact page, Login Component on the login page, etc?

I don't want all of them to load at once, just a simple component that handles the logging in, signing up, etc functions.

I beleive something need to be done on the Bootstrapping part, but what exactly?

**EDIT:** I also might want to use the Login + Signup componenents on one page.

Comment: Following this article http://ngcourse.rangle.io/handout/routing/lazy_loading_of_components.html increasing loading time between pages is bad in terms of UI experience. If you're worrying about loading multiple file don't forget that for a production build, all your file will be merges and minified in one. So this is really not an issue

Comment: Unless you plan to move to SPA shortly, I would suggest something more lightweight (Angular 1.x, Web Components) for non-SPA components. Angular 2 has considerable overhead and never was planned for the thing you want it to use for.

Comment: Angular2 showed quite some progress in producing small output. Not all tools are there yet, but experiments were quite successful. For small apps output size was below the size of Angularjs output. You can't have directives outside Angular2 components. But if you want to add components it's just fine. You just have to create a different Angular2 application for each page (where you want to add different Angular2 functionality).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for your input. I think then I'll stick to Angular 2. What do you personally think about running 2 angular application at the same time? Let's say I have a login feature in the menu and the user should be able to Contact me and Log in from the same page. All should be handled by Angular.

Comment: Are you talking about 2 Angular2 apps on a single page or on two pages? Anyway I think it's fine. You should be aware that Angular works quite well already to develop applications. Deployment especially for you requirements might not yet be satisfying. Many things are work in progress. You should also be aware that Angular2 is quite different from Angular1 in many ways. Angular2 is not made to make fancy hacks with the DOM and JS. Its purpose is rather to build large scale apps with great tool support for static checking.

Comment: Many complain that lots of features they know from Angular1 are not available and and that many things are too cumbersome. This is mostly because Angular2 targets a different kind of apps than Angular1. While I think the argument of code size doesn't really apply (as mentioned above), I also think that Angular1 is probably the better choice for your use case. At least keep that in mind before you complain about Angular2 ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the answers. Yeah I totally understand it. I'm basically planning to make the app's frontend of Laravel Angular 2 and the backend (where the users will be able to use the site) is planned to be built from Angular 2 mostly except a few Laravel middlewares - so that part will be a Single Page app. It will be quite a large application actually. Do you think that Angular 2 is a good choice for this?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've also seen someone doing the exact same thing what I want with drupal here: http://www.mediacurrent.com/blog/building-wundergroundcom-drupal-angular-2-challenge-1-how-bootstrap and he posted a Plunkr also, but it's not good for the Angular 2 RC1 update: http://plnkr.co/edit/A7fyFUST9IdP1FriauXk?p=preview

Comment: Interesting. No idea what id does ;-). The larger the application the better Angular2 will suit.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer The issue is that I don't really know what to update in the Plunkr to make this work, because some stuff got refactored since that build. Any chance that you can take a look at it? :-) Thanks for all your help by the way.

Comment: Sorry, I guess not. I have no idea why this worked in the first place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could bootstrap whatever component you need on that page

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {ContactComponent} from './contact.component';

bootstrap(ContactComponent);
```

Comment: That would mean I'd have to create a full Angular2 app for each page, which isn't ideal. Also, what if I want to use the Login+Signup components on one page?

Comment: Then you have a very simple SPA with only 2 components, ok 3 if you add the AppComponent

Comment: Yes it's definitely a workaround, but let's say I want to use some shared services also. This would make a lot of trash code. I'm sure there's another way to achieve this.

Comment: yes, you can share the service, bootstrap(ContactComponent, ['MySharedService']);

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example for having multiple pages on the same client:

Each client is a angular SPA project.
Which means, the client holds 1 index.html which is routing to the right spa page based on a parameter.

https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/eSq44S

Index.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <span class="navbar-brand">Just Components</span>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="items.html">Items</a></li>
                <li><a href="shapes.html">Shapes</a></li>
                <li><a href="items_and_shapes.html">Items and Shapes</a></li>
                <li><a href="other_static.html">Challenges/Consequences</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h1>Angular 2 Components Without a SPA</h1>
        <table class="table table-bordered lead">
            <tr><td class="col-xs-3 text-right">Home</td><td>There is no angular on this page at all.</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="col-xs-3 text-right">Items</td><td>A static page with Component. Send data <em>OUT</em> of Component <em>TO</em> static page.</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="col-xs-3 text-right">Shapes</td><td>A static page with Component. Send data <em>INTO</em> Component <em>FROM</em> static page.</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="col-xs-3 text-right">Items & Shapes</td><td>Combine everything into one static page.</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="col-xs-3 text-right">Challenges/Consequences</td><td>for consideration, but not insurmountable</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Why?</h4>
        <p>I'm asked routinely if you can put Angular 2 Components on a static page without creating a SPA.</p>
        <p>This is the answer: Yes</p>
        <h4>How?</h4>
        <p>This little app is an <em>imperfect</em> demonstration.</p>
        <p>Forget everything about @NgModel</p>
        <p>Forget everything about System.config path and app settings!</p>
        <p>Forget everything about tradtional Angular 2 bootstrapping!</p>
        <p>Each Component stands alone and boots itself</p>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Items.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Static Pages with Angular 2 Components</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="a2comps/config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/http.min.js"></script>
    <script src="non_angular.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('a2comps/items.ts')
        .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <span class="navbar-brand">Just Components</span>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="items.html">Items</a></li>
                <li><a href="shapes.html">Shapes</a></li>
                <li><a href="items_and_shapes.html">Items and Shapes</a></li>
                <li><a href="other_static.html">Challenges/Consequences</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <items>
                    <div class="text-center"><img src="gears.svg"></div>
                </items>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Send Data OUT of a Component</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <p>Click any row in a table. The row's data will be placed below.</p>
                        <br>
                        <p>The Angular Component generates a custom event. Plain old JS is used to listen for the custom event and update the view traditionally.</p>
                        <br>
                        <div id="itemizer"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Items.ts:

```
import {bootstrap, BROWSER_PROVIDERS, BROWSER_APP_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/platform/browser";
import {Component} from "angular2/core"
import {SimpleTable} from "./simple_table.ts"

@Component({
    selector: "items",
    template: `
    <simple-table [contentTitle]="contentTitle" [tableContent]="items"></simple-table>
  `,
    directives: [SimpleTable]
})

export class Items {
    contentTitle = "Items & Prices";
    items = ITEMS;
}
bootstrap(Items);


//========================
// MOCK DATA
const ITEMS: Item[] = [
    {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "Item 0",
    "price": "$0"
},
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Item 1",
        "price": "$1"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Item 2",
        "price": "$2"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Item 3",
        "price": "$3"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "Item 4",
        "price": "$4"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name": "Item 5",
        "price": "$5"
    }
];
```